# Laravel 5.5 restrict duplicate login

Tags: laravel

I have overwritten **Login** and **Logout** functionality as I need to check many more conditions to authenticate the user like below.

```
public function login(Request $request)
 {
      $this->validateLogin($request);
      $input=$request->all();
      $user=User::where('username',$input['username'])->first();
      //If Temp Password is set
      if(strlen($user->temp_password)>10)
      {
           if (Hash::check($input['password'], $user->temp_password))
           {
                Auth::login($user);
                $this->setUserSession($user);
                $landing_page=Menu::find($user->landing_page);
                return redirect()->route($landing_page->href);

           }
           else {
                session()->put('failure','Invalid Username or Password');
                return redirect('/login');
           }
      }
      else{ //If Temp password is not set
           if (Hash::check($input['password'], $user->password))
           {
                Auth::login($user);
                $this->setUserSession($user);
                $landing_page=Menu::find($user->landing_page);
                return redirect()->route($landing_page->href);
           }
           else {
                session()->put('failure','Invalid Username or Password');
                return redirect('/login');
           }
      }
 }
```

Now I need to restrict Same user from login once again in some other screen or place. I have checked Session Data but nothing is stored as Unique for a User.

ie. If a username **admin** is loged in US the same username **admin** must not be allowed to login from UK.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Oh bagga, question wasn't quite clear. You are trying to restrict the number of sessions to 1 only. If I get it, then you will have to use a `database` session driver. Right now, I think you may be using the default driver (file). It only checks the session within the same browser. Using database session may allow you to check for session everywhere, and restrict the number of connections.

First, make sure your routes are within the `web` middleware so they can access sessions. Then, inside of the web middleware, create a group of routes that are only accessible for users who are not logged in.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@login');
    // any other route
});
```

Logged in users won't be able to access the `login` route anymore.

You could also do the check in your login function to see if the user's is already connected by using

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // user is connected 
    // redirect them
}
```

What does `this->setUserSession($user)` do?

Comment: No, My question is. If a username admin is loged in US the same username admin must not be allowed to  login from UK.

Comment: Ok. the question wasn't quite clear about that. check my update.

Comment: I need to do without using session database. Is there any other way

Comment: Definitely. You can use `redis` also. But you CANNOT use `file` session to accomplish what you are trying to do unless you add an extra column in your user table that says `is_connected = true` when someone is online. So if they have it to true, they cannot sign in from somewhere else. When they log out or session expires, set it back to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using login token.

Generate a login token and keep it in database.
And check for it's entry in database while logging in.
If it doesn't exist let log in success.
Else fail.

And delete login token every time user logs out.

Or

you can generate new token on each login success. And deleting old token and invalidating the old login.

But in this case you have to keep that token in session and for each request you have to check that token with database token.

If it matches, allow user
Else logout the user with notice.

I'll prefer the second method personally.
As you can check for the token in the middleware itself.